# Vimeo embed in Phonegap + Android 4.2

Tags: android, cordova, video, vimeo

i'm developing an app for iOS and Android with Phonegap 2.1.0 and jQuery Mobile 1.2.0. iOS version is already finished but we are experimenting some problems with the Android one...

One of the app sections is a list of videos and they are opened in a iframe inside a pop up, in iOS works well but if we try this in an Android device (Nexus 7 with Android 4.2) we only get the fist screenshot and when we press play only sound is played, without video. We've tryed to open the iframe url with childbrowser in a webview and the result is the same. Only if we open it in an external browser (openExternal) it seems to work.

I think maybe is Vimeo's player problem, but when we try to play the videos, we see this errors in the log:

01-08 22:45:12.084: E/libEGL(26580): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)

01-08 22:45:12.094: D/MediaPlayer(26580): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side

I've been searching for hours without success, so i expect someone may know how to make it works... :/

For the iFrame, we are using the code Vimeo's giving us from the embed section of each video (i can´t post them here cause theyre private), and... Vimeo's option to make video compatible with mobile devices is marked as well.

Thanks!

Comment: iFrames are pretty broken in the Android WebView you may need to find another way to play your Vimeo video.

Comment: Yeah i know, but if we try with the direct url in the childbrowser the result is the same, so this time is not iframe problem :(

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!--
     | WARNING:
     | For iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes.
     | @see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323
     '-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,height=device-height,target-densitydpi=device-dpi,user-scalable=no,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimal-ui">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="close">
        <a href="/cordova:close">fechar</a>
    </div>

    <script id="tmpl-player" type="text/template">
        <iframe id="video" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/[[video]]?autoplay=1&autopause=1&byline=0&badge=0&title=0&portrait=1&color=333&loop=0" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </script>

    <script>
        var bodyEl = document.querySelector('body');
        var tmplPlayerEl = window.document.getElementById('tmpl-player');
        var tmplPlayer = template(tmplPlayerEl.innerHTML, getURLParams());

        function getURLParams() {
            var query = location.search.substr(1);
            var result = {};
            query.split('&').forEach(function(part) {
                var item = part.split('=');
                result[item[0]] = decodeURIComponent(item[1]);
            });
            return result;
        }

        function template(raw, data, keep404) {
            return raw.replace(/\[{2,}[(\s\uFEFF\xA0a-zA-Z0-9_\./]+\]{2,}/gi, function(match, value) {
                value = match.replace(/^\[{2,}|\s+|\]{2,}$/g, '');
                return typeof data[value] !== 'undefined' ? data[value] : (keep404 ? match : '');
            });
        }

        var newNode = window.document.createElement('div');
        newNode.innerHTML = tmplPlayer;
        bodyEl.appendChild(newNode);
    </script>
</body>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
var fsVideo = window.open('vimeo.html?video='+video, '_blank', 'location=no,zoom=no');
fsVideo.addEventListener('loaderror', onLoadError);
fsVideo.addEventListener('loadstop', onLoadStop);
fsVideo.addEventListener('exit', onExit);
function onLoadError(evt){
    fsVideo.close();
}
function onLoadStop(evt){
    evt.url.match('cordova:close') && fsVideo.close();
}
function onExit(evt){
    fsVideo.removeEventListener('loaderror', onLoadError);
    fsVideo.removeEventListener('loadstop', onLoadStop);
    fsVideo.removeEventListener('exit', onExit);
    fsVideo = null;
}
```

Don't forget https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser